# If a class has 50 private members of the same type. Wrap them in a vector/array/dictionary or let them be?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, generics

I have a class which deals with a lot of visuals, which essentially are movieclips. So I have around 50 privately declared movieclips in the class. Would it be a good idea to put them in a dictionary and retrieve them by their name (as key) , put them in an array or just leave them as they are?

My issue is the visual look of my class right now with that many private members, looks like a mess visually.

Comment: Put them in a dictionary

Comment: or array if you think you'll want to access groups of movieclips at any time.

Comment: What if these aren't all movieclips?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, these movieclips are of the same kind or not ? (if they are, just convert your class into a list of movieclips.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code treats them all the same then absolutely put them in an array.  Like if you have a method stop:

```
public function stop() : void {
    for each( var clip : MovieClip in clips ) {
        clip.stop();
    }
}
```

If you are doing a lot of that type of stuff then an array makes sense.  If you are treating them individually like:

```
public function waveHand() : void {
    handWavingClip.play();
}
```

Then using a dictionary might make sense or keeping them as they are.  If you want to clean them up you could group them into classes that the containing class could refer to as well.  I think the dictionary approach might not make much sense given to extract members will take longer than just using an instance variable.  50 private movie clips is big.  I'm guessing this must be a game.  You could also organize around states of the object.  For example store a set of clips under a state they go with.  When a character enters a certain state it could pull out the clips that it needs to perform that state.  That's where a dictionary makes more sense.

Without anymore contextual details that's the best I can offer.  The right structure for your problem probably comes from what you are doing with this stuff.  There is probably a better structure, but without knowing what you are doing we can't see it.

Comment: Yes it's a game. Having classes to store the contextual data, sounds like an excellent idea. Thanks for the detailed help.

Comment: Don't forget that Vector/Array/Dictionary/Object approach, although clean and VERY USEFUL, is slow to access. In a game, this could make the whole difference.